# This.props.navigation out of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

i wanna add a this.props.navigate on my hook. This one is out of my class component so i have this error

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

How i can pass the constructor props on the top ?

Also my hooks

```
function LoginApp() {
    // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
  
    // Handle user state changes
    function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
      setUser(user);
      if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      
      
      const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
      return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
    }, []);
  
    if (initializing) return null;
  
    if (!user) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{textAlign:'center', color:'white', fontSize:48}}>Connexion</Text>
          
         
          
        </View>
      );
    }

  
    
    return (
      
      <View>
        <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('subscribe')}>Créer ma team</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i have this error typeError: navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate('subscribe')', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can also navigate in hook by installing package
npm i @react-navigation/native 
then import it in your file as 
        import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
        const LoginApp = ()=>{
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        return (
           <View>
             <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>Login</Text>
           </View>
           );
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` only works in class, can't work in Hooks so you can do the following way

```
function LoginApp({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('subscribe')}>Créer ma team</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work i have this error TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate('subscribe')', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)

Comment: Did you destructure the `navigation` from props? In your question you're not passing the props at all. Is your LoginApp a screen?

Comment: If you still get an error,probably LoginApp component not defined any navigator.If you call this component from some parent component you should pass navigation prop